# async pipe inside ngIf still gets value

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I want to write a collapsible component which has an "Expand" button that opens a list of items. This list is created through a web request, and I'm wondering when this request happens - since to my understanding the `async` pipe is like a subscription and the `ngIf` would cause the component subscribing to be recreated, I would expect the value of the request to only be available once, however it is created each time I 'show' the expander.

[StackBlitz minimal example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-766npv?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Inside my `AppComponent` I have this logic:

```js
  data$ = of('expensive data from server').pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(() => console.log('data from server emit!')),
    // shareReplay(1),
    finalize(() => console.log('complete!'))
  );
  showSon = true;
```

The template is like this:

```js
<button (click)="showSon=!showSon">Click me!</button>
<p *ngIf="showSon">
  <ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
    <div>{{data}}</div>
  </ng-container>
</p>
```

My understanding is that since the observable is created via `of`, that it should fire its value once and then complete, confirmed by the console logs. However I'm surprised that every time I show the element inside the `ngIf`, I still get a value even though `async` is now subscribing to a completed observable that is not a `ReplaySubject`.

I think using `shareReplay(1)` would solve the issue of making multiple web requests, **but I still don't understand how the single-use observable is repeatedly available whenever the template inside the `ngIf` is recreated.**

Comment: Everytime the If is true, the element gets recreated.. so the async pipe re-subscribes to the data$ observable causing it to emit again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MikeOne's comment is correct. `Everytime the If is true, the element gets recreated.. so the async pipe re-subscribes to the data$ observable causing it to emit again..`

Your solution is also correct, to use [`shareReplay(1)`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) as you've mentioned.